# API to programmatically create an Actions on Google project

Tags: actions-on-google

More precisely can I create an AOG project, that is ready for test, without human action. So either by using APIs only or using APIs and/or CLI's.

The gactions CLI needs a project, so I have to create it on the AOG console first. I can create a project with the cloud control API (or with the gcloud CLI) but those projects are not accepted by gactions. Again I need to go to the console first and "add actions on google" to my project (import).

I hope I'm making sense. The point is programmatically provisioning a skill at least for testing.

Answer (score 2):

This type of API is currently not available.

Comment: Any update on an API to programmatically create, update and share a Google Action? Additionally, enabling Homegraph on the action and creating service account credentials?